# Automatically update the repositories , when install an application

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

As you know when we are use `apt-get update` , it updates packages list .

So when we want to install an application or upgrade the older ones, it's better to run `apt-get update` command to install the Latest application or upgrade to the Latest one .

And here is the question :

What can I do to run `apt-get update` command automatically, when I run `apt-get install Application` or `apt-get upgrade` commands ?

Update : I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 distribution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make aliases that you run instead of the real commands, like this:

```
alias apt-upgrade='sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade'
alias apt-install='sudo apt update && sudo apt install'
```

To test, you can simply define the aliases for your current session only  by running the two lines above directly in your terminal. If you are happy with them, make the definitions persistent for your user account by either appending them to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file or your `~/.bash_aliases` file (which you have to create first in case it doesn't exist yet).

After the aliases are defined one way or the other, you can use them like this:

- running `apt-upgrade` will be equivalent to typing

  ```
  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
  ```
- running `apt-install SOME PACKAGES` will be equivalent to typing

  ```
  sudo apt update && sudo apt install SOME PACKAGES
  ```